# Conditional check for an empty hibernate disjunction

Tags: java, hibernate

Does anybody know how to do a conditional check for an empty disjunction?

> Disjunction dis = Restrictions.disjunction();
>
> if(dis) {
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
if(dis == null || dis.getTypedValues().length == 0)
```

Comment: unfortunately getTypedValues requires additional parameters, so this doens't seem to work. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Junction.html#getTypedValues%28org.hibernate.Criteria,%20org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaQuery%29